# How to set label of Menu Item (GUI MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, label, matlab-guide, submenu

I want to make recent project menu which will look just like this

[image]

It means that i have to set the menu item label each time new project is saved.
how to set it?
i use

```
   set(handles.tag,'String','trial');
```

but it does not work.

Comment: The property you want is not `String`, is `Label`, please refer to the uimenu documentation http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/creating-menus-for-a-programmatic-gui.html

Comment: It works. Thanks...